# Woo commerce and PayPal "We're sorry, but we couldn't complete your purchase using the funding source you selected"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, paypal, checkout

PayPal integrated with Woo Commerce, normally works seamlessly but I'm getting the error in the PayPal Checkout window: "We're sorry, but we couldn't complete your purchase using the funding source you selected. You can complete your purchase with the funding source shown, or choose another way to pay."

I contacted PayPal they said it was the merchant I was using. I know the problem is I have to set all payments allowed on my PayPal settings in woo commerce, but such settings don't exist.

Did anyone experience that before?

Comment: _“they said it was the merchant I was using”_ - that sounds more like you need to make settings in your PayPal merchant account, than in WooCommerce …?

Comment: I have looked in my payment preferences and nothing hints towards accepting different payment methods through PayPal. I contacted there messaging services they just ran in circles, then passed me on to there call services but I can't get through there. I tried deleting woo commerce, but still the same. Anything else to try? @CBroe

Answer (score 0):

This is not a technical problem. I indicates that what was selected could not be used to complete the PayPal payment, and that an alternative was offered. If the alternative was not acceptable, then the "anther way to pay" being suggested would be a way that is not PayPal. That is all, basically. It's all going to be expected behavior as far as PayPal is concerned.